# Resolve src dir for imports in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I configure React Native to import files relative to the `src` directory? In other words, I want to write `import Foo from 'components/foo'` rather than `import Foo from '../../components/foo'`.

When using webpack it can be configured like [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root). With [React Native packager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager) I haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I haven't found a solution that let's you import exactly the way you want, but there are several suggestions of how to configure import locations in [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099).

## [My favorite solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-221815006)

(Works in any JavaScript project, not just React Native, and let's you write very short paths to reference files.)

Create a `package.json` in your `src/` directory with the contents:

```
{
    "name": "src"
}
```

What this does is say: This folder is a package, named `src`. Then you can import any file/directory inside that package by simply adding it's position (relative to the directory the `package.json` is in) after the name of the package:

```
import Foo from 'src/components/foo';
```

## [Another solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-155628204)

In any React Native Project, you can do:

```
import Foo from 'MyApp/src/components/foo';
```

where `MyApp`  is whatever name you registered in your `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` files.

The app name is registered using one of the [AppRegistry](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html) methods, such as

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => AppRootComponent);
```

Answer (score 3):

A good solution is to make your babel resolve all the logical paths before it transpile. You can accomplish this by adding [babel-plugin-root-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-root-import) to you're node dependencies and changing you're .babelrc, similar to the code bellow:

```
"plugins": [
["babel-plugin-root-import", {
  "rootPathSuffix": "src"
}]
]
```

Now you can refer to all your components inside src like this

```
import Component from '~/business/ComponentExample'
```

Comment: I have used this before, so I don't remember why I couldn't use this solution (perhaps it didn't work with React Native at the time). Can you do this in React Native projects now?